# In WPF can I attach the same click handler to multiple buttons at once like I can in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have multiple buttons instead of doing

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
etc.
this.button10.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this in pseudo-code:

```
this.button*.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
```

In Javascript it is possible is there something like that in WPF ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In WPF, `Button.Click` is a [routed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx), which means that the event is routed up the visual tree until it's handled. That means you can add an event handler in your XAML, like this:

```
<StackPanel Button.Click="button_Click">
    <Button>Button 1</Button>
    <Button>Button 2</Button>
    <Button>Button 3</Button>
    <Button>Button 4</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Now all the buttons will share a single handler (button_Click) for their Click event.

That's an easy way to handle the same event across a group of controls that live in the same parent container. If you want to do the same thing from code, you can use the AddHandler method, like this:

```
AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler( button_Click));
```

That'll add a handler for every button click in the window. You might want to give your StackPanel a name (like, "stackPanel1") and do it just for that container:

```
stackPanel1.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler( button_Click));
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't ask for doing this programmatically but you read in my mind :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making `button1`, `button2` etc, make a List of buttons.

Then you can write:

```
myList.ForEach( b => b.Click += button_Click );
```

From XAML you can attach the click handler to the parent of the buttons something like this (I use a StackPanel as an example):

```
<StackPanel Button.Click="button_Click">
  <Button .... >First button</Button>
  <Button .... >Second button</Button>
  <Button .... >Third button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This works because the buttons Click event is a **bubbling routed event**.

Comment: Good explanation thank you very much the ForEach I'm not accustomed to but will learn it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Linq To VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) to locate all the buttons in your Window / UserControl, then iterate over this list adding your event handler.

```
var buttons = this.Descendants<Button>().Cast<Button>();
foreach(var button in buttons)
{
  button.Click += button_Click;
}
```

I think that is about as concise as you are going to get it!

Comment: Very interesting for complex project at the moment I just need basics.