# WPF has no "neutral" or invisble panel how to create one?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I asked a question here about a panel just for having inheritance for event handlers:
[Problem with WPF Stackpanel: how can I group elements in Circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780494/problem-with-wpf-stackpanel-how-can-i-group-elements-in-circle)

There seems to be any ! Any simple tutorial on easiest wau to create such invisible custom panel ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Behavior as opposed to a grupping UI element. Do you have your radial panel implemented?

Comment: I'm beginner I don't know about Behavior and radial panel but I prefer something that is really like grouping in concept because specific tricks may not work because of some details.

Comment: No worries, the point I wastrying to make is inheritance is not a WPF way of doing things. If you need to add some extra functional, you better of appending it to the existing imeplementation. Could you tell us what's your challange?