# How to attach 2 methods to button click in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two methods that need to be called when a button is pressed.

I can do it by code in this way

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click_1);
```

but how can I do it in XAML?

Comment: probably no. but what's the sense to do it in this way? they are executed sequentially so it makes no difference if you paste one code after another.

Comment: it makes sense when I have inherited a form, and want to extend it's buttons functionality, but don't want to write that in code

Comment: But in that case, why not just override the inherited button_Click function.

Comment: because I'll lose the initial function, let's say my base forms button does some functionality, I want my inherited forms button du the same, AND some additional stuff,but don't want to duplicate the code. It would be better to do it just adding the new function to the button's event stack, which is pretty easy in winforms designer.cs

Comment: I hope I'm not misunderstanding but you can call `base(sender, e)` at the start of your inherited (virtual) handler function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your form is one of your own, meaning you can change it.

Consider using a **virtual** method.

```
public class MyForm
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        //Some code.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello from MyForm");
    }
}

public class MyOtherForm : MyForm
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        //Call the base DoSomething first
        base.DoSomething();

        //Some code to run after.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello from MyOtherForm");
    }
}
```

If you want to achieve this in `XAML`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780132/in-wpf-can-i-attach-the-same-click-handler-to-multiple-buttons-at-once-like-i-ca) as it has already been answered.

Comment: useful post, but so no way to do the adding in the xaml?)

Comment: Yes, you can. I have edited my answer for you with further information.