# event handler + formatting multiple buttons - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, stackpanel

actually I got two problems that I want to solve and bring together in my wpf application.

I have multiple buttons which have a specific layout.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="greenButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
     </Style>
     ...        
</Window.Resources>
```

ok, fine and here are my buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="btn100" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource greenButton}">100</Button>
<Button x:Name="btn101" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource greenButton}">101</Button>
<Button x:Name="btn102" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource greenButton}">102</Button>
```

Then, after a Button-Click I want to trigger a method, that needs the caption of the Button

```
    private void btn100_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        name = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        doMethod(name);
    }
```

Ok. But I have so many buttons so I want to bring then together with the same click - event handler. I tried this:

```
<StackPanel Button.Click="button_Click" Grid.RowSpan="20">
     <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" Style="{StaticResource greenButton}">LT 1</Button>
     <Button x:Name="btn100" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource greenButton}">100</Button>
     <Button x:Name="btn101" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource greenButton}">101</Button>
     <Button x:Name="btn102" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource greenButton}">102</Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

My c# Code is now:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        name= (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        doMethod(name);
    }
```

**And now I got my two problems:**

1. the row-alignment doesnt work for my buttons. With the stackpanel they are now bigger/ higher than my rows, that I definied in my Grid
2. I dont get the button name. It's always null

Thx for help in advance.

Edit:
No duplicate of [In WPF can I attach the same click handler to multiple buttons at once like I can in Javascript/Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780132/in-wpf-can-i-attach-the-same-click-handler-to-multiple-buttons-at-once-like-i-ca)  My solution is based on this post but I have problems going one step further (layout + transfer variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In WPF can I attach the same click handler to multiple buttons at once like I can in Javascript/Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780132/in-wpf-can-i-attach-the-same-click-handler-to-multiple-buttons-at-once-like-i-ca)

Comment: no duplicate. My solution is based on this post but I have problems going one step further (layout + transfer variables)

Comment: As a note, it is of course not necessary to introduce the StackPanel (which obviously destroys your layout). You could as well assign `Button.Click` at the Grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign the `Button.Click` handler to the StackPanel, the sender argument of the handler method is not a Button, hence `(sender as Button)` returns null.

You may write `(e.OriginalSource as Button)` instead, by it's probably simpler to assign the Click handler to all Buttons by an `EventSetter` in your Style:

```
<Style x:Key="greenButton" TargetType="Button">
    ...
    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="button_Click"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I removed the stackpanel and implemented your suggestion and now... it works :) Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think, sender is in this case the StackPanel. Try to use:

```
string name = (e.OriginalSource as Button)?.Content.ToString();
```